# Counting the number of words in a text area

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea

Hello everyone my first question on stack overflow

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
static int count=0;
String ct;
JTextField word;
JTextArea tohide;
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    TI ti=new TI();
}

public TI()
{

    JPanel j=new JPanel();
    JLabel def=new JLabel("Enter the text to be encrypted");
    word=new JTextField("",20);
    tohide=new JTextArea("",5,20);
    JButton jb=new JButton("COUNT");
    tohide.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    j.add(def);
    j.add(tohide);
    j.add(word);
    j.add(jb);
    add(j);
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jb.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

    String txt=tohide.getText();
    StringTokenizer stk=new StringTokenizer(txt," ");
    while(stk.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String token=stk.nextToken();
        count++;
    }
    ct=Integer.toString(count);;
    word.setText(ct);

   }

    }
```

I want to count the number of words that are being typed in the textarea.There is a logical error.As I keep clicking the count button the word count increases.

Comment: 1) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 2) +1 for posting code, describing the actual behavior (I think we can guess the expected behavior) & figuring out how to use the code formatting.  3) Welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 7):

You never reset the `count` to 0 before recalculating the number of words. There doesn't seem to be a need for `count` to be a class variable. Making that change would make this kind of mistake impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Use `javax.swing.text.Utilities` which has

```
public static final int getWordStart(JTextComponent c, int offs)
public static final int getWordEnd(JTextComponent c, int offs)
```

Separating by spaces is not enough. The separator could be also tab, \n etc. chars

Answer (score 1):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    word.setText(String.valueOf(tohide.getText().split("\\s").length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to do the task. The idea behind it is that each pair of words is separated by a space. hence using space to split seems straight forward. if words contain carriage return, then, replacing the carriage return with empty string has to be done before counting. I hope that it helps

```
 public int WordCount(String Words){
   //Initiate Result
     String s = Words+" "; //Add space after the received string
     String result ="";
     int i = 0;
     int count = s.length();

    try {

        for (i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++) {
              if (count - i > 1) {

                String tempString = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" "));



                if (s.contains(" ") && (!s.isEmpty())) {
                    s = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1, s.length());
                    //get substring between " " and lenght ;
                } else {
                    if(!s.isEmpty()) {
                        //output nothing
                    } 
                }
            } else {
                //output nothing;
            }

        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }




    return i;

}
```